# R server 9.0.1 still fails to rxImport huge data

Tags: microsoft-r

I am eager to use Microsoft R server to deal with real big data in hadoop compute context. It works well to deal with not large data. 
But it fails when data is large with the following error:

[image: Error result]

Comment: ..and what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using RxHdfsFileSystem for your input/output data source? Are you running in Hadoop compute context or local?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug when trying to import large data from HDFS into a single data-frame. Currently, you can work around this issue by copying the data from HDFS into your local file system, and then importing it into a data-frame directly.

Thank you,

Kirill